# Unable to install Seurat or devtools on R 3.5.2

Tags: r, seurat

I have R version 3.5.2. Up until July, I had no issue installing and running Seurat and devtools. I understand that R version 4 is now available, and Seurat v3 needs R 3.6 or higher installed. Recently, I opened up Rstudio (which also happens to be the older version 1.1), and tried to run Seurat commands. When that did not work, I tried to install Seurat again using CRAN using:
install.packages("Seurat")
I also used Biocmanager. Both times, I got an error message saying Seurat is not available for R 3.5.2. Well, what exactly happened in the span of a month or so?! It was running fine before.
Also, I cannot install and run devtools. I get a bunch of error messages saying some dependencies are not available and a 'no zero exit status' message.
What does this all mean? Do I need to upgrade to newer versions?
Thanks!

Comment: CRAN doesn't maintain full support for older versions of R.  You can install packages into them, but it takes experience to get it right.  You're much better off staying with the latest version of R.  Currently that's 4.0.2.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just had the latest versions of R and R studio installed. Hope it works!